# Update time value for every second row

Tags: mysql, sql, dateadd

I am trying to update a time value in my MySQL table and am having trouble working the logic out.

I want to make it so it reads:

```
ID  Time
1   17:00
2   17:00
3   17:08
4   17:08
5   17:16
6   17:16
```

and so on.

I can select every second row by using MOD on the ID number but I am having trouble specifying the correct update value for the row.

```
UPDATE `table`
set `Time` = DATE_ADD(Convert('17:00:00',TIME),INTERVAL (`ID`-2)*8 MINUTE)
where `ID` mod 2 = 1
```

If you require any clarifications please let me know and thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I should add that if I there is a query that can update like the table above then that would be even better!

Comment: do you want to update every two rows or every 2nd row? your update will update every 2nd row only. try the same where condition with a select * from table where `ID` mod 2 = 1 . if you can use use a stored procedure. simpler in my opionion and can print debug info. or a php/ jsp script

Comment: `where \`ID\` mod 2 = 1` is probably *not* a good idea. I think you *shouldn't* assume that ID are consecutive. They might be "hole", say because of failed concurrent transaction. Isn't there any other column that would allow you to discriminate the "pair" of rows?

Comment: It won't work for row 2 but subsequent row should work... (like row 4, row 6 etc.)

Comment: I should add that if I there is a query that can update like the table above then that would be even better!

Comment: @SylvainLeroux All the ID's are concurrent in the table. There are no holes.

Comment: @S2333 This is a "one shot" thing? Or do you have to do that regularly while your application is working "normally"?

Comment: Just a one shot query. It does not need to be run regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is what you want:

```
update tbl set `Time` =
           ADDDATE('1970-01-01 17:00:00', INTERVAL 8*((`ID`-1) DIV 2) MINUTE);
```

Producing (for a table already having rows ID1~6):

```
mysql> select * from tbl;
+------+----------+
| ID   | Time     |
+------+----------+
|    1 | 17:00:00 |
|    2 | 17:00:00 |
|    3 | 17:08:00 |
|    4 | 17:08:00 |
|    5 | 17:16:00 |
|    6 | 17:16:00 |
+------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

your mod is selecting impair numbers not pair numbers (every second)

try this

```
      where `ID` mod 2 = 0
```